# How to force the user to input in a particular format?

Tags: python

Is there is a way to make sure that the user enters the input data as I want them to, 
For example,
I wrote this code so the user can enter some birthdays and the script will choose one in random:

```
import random, re

print("keep in mind that you need to enter the date in this format dd/mm/yyyy")

cont_1 = input("please enter the informations of the 1st contestant : \n")
cont_2 = input("please enter the informations of the 2nd contestant : \n")
cont_3 = input("please enter the informations of the 3rd contestant : \n")
cont_4 = input("please enter the informations of the 4th contestant : \n")
cont_5 = input("please enter the informations of the 5th contestant : \n")

print("Thank you,")

win = cont_1 + " " + cont_2 + " " + cont_3 + " " + cont_4 + " " + cont_5

contDates = re.compile(r'\d\d/\d\d/\d\d\d\d')
ir = contDates.findall(win)
print(" And the Winner is: ", random.choice(ir))
```

I want to know if there is a way to force the user to write in the input in this format ../../... when he enters the first two digits a slash shows and the next two

Comment: You could use a `while` loop to keep asking for the input as long as it doesn't have the correct format. However, it might also make sense for your program to be able to handle / identify different input formats.

Comment: @martineau This is not a duplicate, although the answers are the same, the question is something else.

Comment: @MegaIng The duplicate target is not that different. The only different part is a validation rule. I strongly believe that the closure is justified.

Comment: @MegaIng: I disagree — the gist, or central idea (as well as the solution) is identical.

Comment: As an aside, unless there is a good reason not to do so, variable and function names should follow the `lower_case_with_underscores` style.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not easy way to do this. The easiest solution is to just check that what the user input is correct before asking for the next input:

```
date_re = re.compile(r'\d\d/\d\d/\d\d\d\d')
def ask_date(prompt):
    while True: # Ask forever till the user inputs something correct.
        text = input(prompt)
        if date_re.fullmatch(text): # Does the input match the regex completly (e.g. no trailing input)?
             return text # Just return the text. This will break out of the loop
        else:
             print("Invalid date format. please use dd/mm/yyyy")

cont_1 = ask_date("please enter the informations of the 1st contestant : \n")
cont_2 = ask_date("please enter the informations of the 2nd contestant : \n")
cont_3 = ask_date("please enter the informations of the 3rd contestant : \n")
cont_4 = ask_date("please enter the informations of the 4th contestant : \n")
cont_5 = ask_date("please enter the informations of the 5th contestant : \n")
```

This also simplifies the selection process, since all dates are valid:

```
print(" And the Winner is: ", random.choice((cont_1, cont_2, cont_3, cont_4, cont_5))
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23294658/asking-the-user-for-input-until-they-give-a-valid-response

Answer (score 1):

You can check if it is correct date format like this without using regex.

```
import datetime
user_input = input()

try:
  datetime.datetime.strptime(user_input,"%d/%m/%Y")
except ValueError as err:
  print('Wrong date format')
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23294658/asking-the-user-for-input-until-they-give-a-valid-response

Answer (score -1):

If you want it custom:

```
i = input("date (dd/mm/yyyy):")
split = i.split("/")
for item in split:
    try:
        int(item)
    except:
        print("error")
        exit()
if len(split) != 3 or len(split[0]) not in [1, 2] or len(split[1]) not in [1, 2] or len(split[2]) != 4:
    print("error!")
else:
    print("accepted!")
```

This makes sure that all of the items are numbers, and that there are 3 slashes, the first and second ones are two digits, and the last one is 4 digits. If you want to accept any correct date:

Comment: What makes this better than a regex? It's harder to read and it doesn't verify that it is just numbers.

Comment: @MegaIng -- It's faster to implement, and for non-regex readers, it is easy to read.

Comment: You are going to have a hard time to convince me that anyone will look at this piece of code and immediately understand what it does. For a simple regex, this should be the case. Also, the regex version is easy to maintain and change in the future. (and your version allows negative numbers in dates right now).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23294658/asking-the-user-for-input-until-they-give-a-valid-response